# code crashing with no logic error

Tags: c++, debugging, crash

I made a sudoku solver by backtracking (kinda messy code but i think it should work), I have gone through the code several times but i cant see why it crashes,I would really appreciate it if someone can spot it thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#define N 25
using namespace std;

bool backtrack(int sudoku[N][N],int n);
bool analyze(int sudoku[N][N],int n);

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int  sudoku[N][N];
  int  n=0,i,j;
  char c=0;

  cin.get(c);

  while(c!='\n')
  {
    if(c==32)
    {
      cin.get(c);
      sudoku[0][n]=c;
      continue;
    }

    cin.get(c);
    n++;
  }

  // cout<<"n is"<<n<<endl;
  // cout<<"part 1"<<endl;

  for(i=1; i<n; i++)
  {
    for(j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
      cin>>sudoku[n][j];
    }
  }

  for(i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
      // cout<<sudoku[n][j];
    }
  }

  if(backtrack(sudoku,n))
  {
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
      for(j=0; j<n; j++)
      {
        cout<<sudoku[i][j]<<" ";
      }

      cout<<endl;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    cout<<"NO";
  }

  return 0;
}

bool analyze(int sudoku[N][N],int n)
{
  int i,j,k,f,g,l,m;
  int compare[N]={0};
  // cout<<"analyze test start";

  for(i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    for(j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
      if(compare[sudoku[i][j]]==1)
      {
        // cout<<"before return false test 1";
        return false;
      }
      compare[sudoku[i][j]]=1;
    }

    for(k=0; k<n; k++)
    {
      compare[k]=0;
    }
  }

  for(k=0; k<n; k++)
  {
    compare[k]=0;
  }

  for(j=0; j<n; j++)
  {
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
      if(compare[sudoku[i][j]]==1)
      {
        // cout<<"before return false test 2";
        return false;
      }
      compare[sudoku[i][j]]=1;
    }

    for(k=0; k<n; k++)
    {
      compare[k]=0;
    }
  }

  for(k=0; k<n; k++)
  {
    compare[k]=0;
  }

  for(f=0; f<=n; f+=3)
  {
    for(g=0; g<=n; g+=3)
    {
      for(l=0+f; l<3+f; l++)
      {
        for(m=0+g; m<3+g; m++)
        {
          if(compare[sudoku[l][m]]==1)
          {
            // cout<<"before return false test 3";
            return false;
          }
          compare[sudoku[l][m]]=1;
        }
      }

      for(k=0; k<n; k++)
      {
        compare[k]=0;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
  //cout<<"analyze test finish";
}

bool backtrack(int sudoku[N][N],int n)
{
  int i,j,value=0;
  // cout<<"backtract test start";

  for(i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    for(j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
      if(sudoku[i][j]==0)
      {
        assign:
        sudoku[i][j]=value;
        if(analyze(sudoku,n))
        {
          if(backtrack(sudoku,n))
          {
            return true;
          }
          else
          {
            sudoku[i][j]=0;
          }
        }
        else
        {
          value++;
          if(value>n)
          {
            return false;
          }
          goto assign;
        }
      }
      value=0;
    }
  }
  //cout<<"backtract test finish";
  return true;
}
```

Comment: it crashes because the code has terrible intendation. Sorry just joking, please format your code so it is readable

Comment: Start by running in a debugger to catch the crash in action and locate where it happens in your code.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: I tried your code on ideone and it didn't crash (https://ideone.com/5FgHh1), so it's not really possible to help. However, I would kindly advice you to clean your code first if you still have problems. It seems that there is a lot of useless code in your `analyze` function. Also, you assign some of your loop counter like `m=0+f`, which is disturbing and you use a `goto` in a recursion which is hard to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a fixed array int sudoku[N][N] and never check for boundaries. If any of the indexes exceeds the appropriate dimension size, you can have a problem. In the very least you should add 
if(n >= N) break; inside your while(c != '\n') loop.
A better solution would be allocating the array dynamically or using std::vector.